# pandas.Series inducing KeyError in pyplot.hist

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I generate a Dataframe.  I pull a Series of floats out of it, and plot it in a histogram.  Works fine.

But when I generate a sub-series of that data, using either of the two descriptions:

```
u83 = results['Wilks'][results['Weight Class'] == 83]
u83 = results[results['Weight Class'] == 83]['Wilks']
```

pyplot.hist throws a KeyError on that Series.

```
#this works fine
plt.hist(results['Wilks'], bins=bins)
# type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(results['Wilks']))
# type is <type 'numpy.float64'>
print(type(results['Wilks'][0]))

#this histogram fails with a KeyError for both of these selectors:
u83 = results['Wilks'][results['Weight Class'] == 83]
u83 = results[results['Weight Class'] == 83]['Wilks']
print u83
#type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(u83))
#plt.hist(u83) fails with a KeyError
plt.hist(u83)
```

I just started messing with Pandas.  Perhaps I'm not groking the right way to do the sql-equivalent of 'select * from table where WeightClass = 83' etc?

Answer (score 7):

Oh, solved it....  pass the Series with its values attribute.

```
plt.hist(u83.values)
```

Sort of weird.

As a backtrace -- now any of my sub-selection methods worked.  It was simply that I was passing `plt.hist(u83)` instead of `plt.hist(u83.values)`....  Sort of lame.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
u83 = results.loc[results['Weight Class'] == 83, 'Wilks']
plt.hist(u83)
```

And you might want to read these [docs on indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)...

Comment: yeah, afraid this gives the same error.  The Series itself looks normal to me.    [In] u83
Out[15]: 
3     410.370158
5     379.581755
14    361.213206
23    349.908011
29    335.061991
50    308.511000
51    306.523497
53    304.869996
57    302.155009
68    289.432998
69    288.466504
Name: Wilks, dtype: float64

Comment: Figured out the answer.